# Angular Array list .get method not working

Tags: arrays, angular, arraylist, typoscript

I am trying to Check two Array list ( any = [] and FormArray) each array list has multiple items

Array 1
[image]

Array 2
[image]

I want to check UoMName and SubBaseUoMCode is equal

if I run this code

```
    for (let i = 0; this.UOMList.length > i; i++) {
      
     console.log( this.UOMList[i].get('UoMName'));
      
      for (let i2 = 0; this.BaseUoMDetails.length > i2; i2++) {
        console.log(this.BaseUoMDetails.value[i2].get('UoMName'));
       
        if (this.UOMList[i].get('UoMName') == this.BaseUoMDetails.value[i2].get('SubBaseUoMCode') ) {
          console.log("checked");
        }
       
      

      }      
      debugger
    }
```

[image]

I am trying to fix this using (.at, .console). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       for (let i = 0; this.UOMList.length > i; i++) {
         console.log( this.UOMList[i]['UoMName']);
          
          for (let i2 = 0; this.BaseUoMDetails.length > i2; i2++) {
            console.log(this.BaseUoMDetails.value[i2]['UoMName']);
           
            if (this.UOMList[i]['UoMName'] == this.BaseUoMDetails.value[i2]['SubBaseUoMCode'] ) {
              console.log("checked");
            }
           
          
    
          }      
          debugger
     

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To access property `UoMName` inside the array `UOMList` and `BaseUoMDetails` you have to change your code a little bit. Try the code below=>

```
for (let i = 0; this.UOMList.length > i; i++) {
     console.log( this.UOMList[i].get('UoMName'));
      for (let i2 = 0; this.BaseUoMDetails.length > i2; i2++) {
        console.log(this.BaseUoMDetails[i2]['UoMName']);
        if (this.UOMList[i].get('UoMName') == this.BaseUoMDetails[i2]['SubBaseUoMCode'] ) {
          console.log("checked");
        }
      }      
      //debugger
}
```